# How do I write an array to color all jpanels I needed

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write an array to color JPanels that I needed

```
        jPanel_day_trans.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_product.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_Day.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_Day_past.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_month.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_wedd.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_sidepanel_trans.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,165));
        jPanel_Day_Day.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPanel_Month.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPane_Product.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jPane_Weddings.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
        jLabel_Date.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest to set the background the same for all panels it to simply use:

```
panel.setBackground( null );
```

when you create the panel. Then the panel will have the same background as its parent panel. So there is no need for an array. You simply change the background of the top level panel in your frame.

This approach will only work if the background color is opaque.

You can't really use transparent backgrounds on all your panels because the transparency is additive. So each time you add a panel to another panel the child panel will be less transparent and therefore darker in color.

Instead, if you are trying to set the background of all the panels on the frame then the easiest way is to make all panels transparent:

```
panel.setOpaque( false );
```

Then you would set the background color of the top panel that is used as the content pane:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color(0, 0, 0, 100) );
```

Comment: do I have to do it one by one for the panels